# Application for updating database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

i have published my website...its a dynamic site..so i have database connectivity..now i want to make an application in VB to update my database using my application..i mean i do not want to login to the site and update my database rather update it using my application..i want to connect my application  to the database of the published site and update it from anywhere i want using the application...is it possible??

How can i do it??Please point me to the right direction...its urgent.

Answer (score 1):

you can turn on `AllowRemoteConnections` in your SQLServer. so your application from any where can connect to it and update the DB.

but the best practice for this is using a `WCF Service`. You should place your methods for updating the DB in a WCF Service farm and then write a client application using Windows Forms or WPF to connect to WCF Service and update the DB using Provided methods in WCF Service.

Comment: i just want to insert or update table columns or rows...dats all i want..what is the best approach??

Comment: Best approach is using WCF Services in your webserver and a tiny windows form application witch is doing updates using provided services

Comment: can u provide me with any tutorial??

Answer (score 0):

Although what you want to do is possible you probably don't want to do that.  If you are hosting your site with an ISP the hosting company will need to provide the access.

However, as Farzin suggests, you need an integration layer between your application and the database.

You could go with a WCF Service but if it is something simple you could even expose your data using something like MVC.

All you basically need is the security wrapped around your database.

Comment: i just want to insert or update table columns or rows...dats all i want..what is the best approach??

Comment: There is no best approach :) --- use what you are comfortable with as long as it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: can u provide me with any tutorial??

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at Lightswitch? It is currently Beta2 but still quite robust. Using Lightswitch you can quickly set up an app which performs CRUD operations on your database.